# Повторное вычисление номера блока по клику не работает

Tags: javascript

При помощи данного куска кода я определяю на какой по счету элемент внутри блока я кликнул:

```
document.querySelector('#block').addEventListener("click", function(evt){
      let child = this.children;
      log = [].indexOf.call(this.children, evt.target);
});
```

При первом клике выдается правильный результат, но если повторно кликнуть на тот же самый элемент внутри блока, то выдает результат "-1". Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: `indexOf()` возвращает `-1` в том случае, когда элемент в массиве не найден. Вероятно, у тебя это происходит при всплытии события, а не при повторном клике. Исправить можно либо введя проверку на какое-то свойство целевого элемента (которым обладают только дочерние элементы), например проверять класс через `classList.contains()` или `matches()`... либо, обрабатывая событие на этапе захвата, а не всплытия (насчет второго варианта не уверен).

Comment: Можно также прекращать всплытие (выражением `evt.stopPropagation();`), но это считается плохой практикой - т.к. в таком случае, событие не получат _вообще все_ элементы "выше" по вложенности (а не только те что в `#block`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставлю тут как пример.

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onListClick = this.onListClick.bind(this);

    this.list = this.node.querySelector(".list");

    this.list.addEventListener("click", this.onListClick, false);
  }

  onListClick(event) {
    const item = event.target.closest(".item");

    if (!item) return;

    const index = [...this.list.children].indexOf(item);

    console.log(index); // index + 1 position
  }
}

new myClass(document.querySelector(".container"));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
    <li class="item">5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPD.**

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".item")].forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    const index = [...document.querySelector("#block").children].indexOf(item);
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы не подскажите мне как теперь имея индекс элемента, обратиться к самому элементу? Например, я хочу обратиться к 21 элементу в div'е "block", но я знаю только номер элемента и хочу изменить его свойство innerHTML/

Comment: @Draktharon, ну, например можно занести список всех элементов в переменную и обратиться по индексу, например: `array[index].innerHTML`